# How to create stacked bar chart in Excel using C# Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio

Can anyone help me how to create stacked bar chart in Excel using a C# Windows Forms application where the datasource is an array? I've created the chart like you can see in screenshot #1. But I want to create stacked bar chart like another one + labels.

Thank you

[Screenshot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxaGQ.png)

[Screenshot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxVMe.png)

Comment: What is 'stacked bar chart', you'd better show some images.

Comment: oh i'm sorry. i've updated my question

Comment: I also changed my vote, but, you should read docs first.

Comment: I've been search any topics but still have not found what I need.

Comment: Try [this example](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/excel-chart-components/303), note that the sample is live and you can interact with it by changing the values of "Chart type", "Chart grouping", etc. The C# code uses [GemBox.Spreadsheet](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/overview).